# bash script to incremental backup file or folder from cifs volume to local storage

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script where i'm mounting a windows file share as a cifs volume in centos 7 to taking an incremental backup of files that has been changed yesterday , please find my code below and let me know how to proceed on this.

I have mounted my windows file share as CIFS as below

```
mount -t cifs -o username=XXXX,password=XXXX,domain=XXX //172.16.36.3/d /Windows/Point -rw
```

with the help of below script i'm trying to take incremental backup

```
tod=`date +%F`
yest=`date  +%F --date="1 days ago"`
path=/Windows/Point
cp -av `find $path -type f -newermt $yest ! -newermt $tod` /Windows/Backup/destination
```

But the real problem is while executing the cp command i get an error stating

> cp: cannot stat No such file or directory

As i checked the windows folder mounted has a folder name with space like " test document" where the script breakes after test and i get those error.

Can anyone help please..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what output do you get when you just run `find $path -type f -newermt $yest ! -newermt $tod`   ?  Does this return the folder name "test document" ?

Comment: Once it is mounted via `cifs` it is just another part of the filesystem. Once you confirm the mount (say with the `mount` command -- no arguments), you can simply use `rsync -ua /Windows/Point /destination` (presuming a successful of `/Windows/Point`)

Comment: @EJK i'm able to find the list of files that has been modified yesterday.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : my goal is to take incremental backup only. Does rsync performance only incremental backup without taking full backup.

Comment: By default, `rsync` will create a `mirror` of the original. `-u` tells it to only copy new/changed files. However, you can use it (or `diff`) to generate a list of only new changed files from which you could generate an *incremental-only* backup.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks david will try doing that.. But the diff command will not see that modified files it only count the newly created files. Am i rite

Comment: See the `--list-only` option to `rsync` for generating the *new/changed* files list.